# Cron daemon error : Permission Denied

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am having trouble setting up a cron job. My set up is as follows:

```
crontab -e

*/10 * * * * OTP_ProJect/PandaServerInfo/SVN/PandaQueueMonitoring/trunk/submit_cron_test.sh
```

the shell script has permissions:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 submit_cron_test.sh
```

submit_cron_test.sh submits a python script:

```
python2.5 ProcessPlant.py --test
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
/bin/sh: /OTP_ProJect/PandaServerInfo/SVN/PandaQueueMonitoring/trunk/submit_cron_test.sh: Permission denied
```

I have tried the command

```
/bin/sh /OTP_ProJect/PandaServerInfo/SVN/PandaQueueMonitoring/trunk/submit_cron_test.sh
```

and this works fine.

Has anyone got any ideas, because I have ran out. :-(

Comment: Path permissions?  Who owns the file, and who owns the process that's trying to open it for execution?

Comment: I am the owner of the file. The permission I have set is chmod u+x submit_cron_test.sh, but I am not the root user or have any admin privileges. the path permisions for /bin/sh has all users and groups rwx

Comment: @MWright, the excerpt from the crontab file is "OTP_ProJect/..." **WITHOUT** a leading slash.

Comment: Your test of `sh /OTP_ProJect/...` does not test the executability of the script, only it's readability.  Try it directly without the sh prefix.  In particular, try the line exactly as it is in crontab.  Also, the script is only executable by the file owner.  I assume that that user is the same as the user who's crontab has the above entry.

Answer (score 3):

Is `submit_cron_test.sh` owned by you? Only the owner can execute it directly. Prepending `/bin/sh` causes the `sh` command to read the script from the file, which any user can do.

You can do `chmod a+x` on the `submit_cron_test.sh` file.

Also does your script have a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`) line?

Comment: I am the owner of the file. The permission I have set is chmod u+x submit_cron_test.sh, but I am not the root user or have any admin privileges . I have the shebang set to #!/bin/zsh

Comment: Hi, 

The server that I am working on doesn't have a token for cron jobs...so I have been told.

Therefor I am getting the above error.

I will move to a local machine to run my cron job.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: @MWright If this solved your problem you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)